# How to add form groups dynamically on button click in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to make a form where need to add more fields dynamically on button click.
On every click, I will be appending 2 fields ( a group ).
I have tried so far:

I created an array of dictionaries that would hold the values for those 2 fields( group ).

It looks something like this.

`@State var record = [["before": 300, "after": 280],["before": 300, "after": 260]]`

Then I have a button where on click (incrementing counter) I am appending a dictionary to the above array, that way it should add a new form group(2 fields)

This is my view, I am using forEach to loop and render the items.

```
ForEach(0..<counter, id: \.self) { index in
                    TextField("Before value", text: $record[index]["before"])
                    TextField("After value", text: $record[index]["after"])
                }
```

But by doing that It is giving the following error.
[image]

How do I get it to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextField` must require a `String` binding and in your code, you are using `Int`. So first you need to declare your dictionary as a `[String: String]` type and then use custom binding. Like this.

```
@State var record = [["before": "300", "after": "280"],["before": "300", "after": "260"]]

TextField("Before value", text: Binding(get: {(record[0]["before"] ?? "")}, set: {record[0]["before"] = $0}))
TextField("After value", text: Binding(get: {(record[0]["after"] ?? "")}, set: {record[0]["after"] = $0}))
```

---

---

If you still want to go with Int then you can use it by this.

```
@State var record = [["before": 300, "after": 280],["before": 300, "after": 260]]

TextField("Before value", value: Binding(get: {(record[0]["before"])}, set: {record[0]["before"] = $0}), formatter: NumberFormatter())
```